# Building Omnet++ projects through ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, omnet++, inet

My Omnet++ IDE is not building projects due to java heap error. So i have tried building the projects through terminal. I can successfully build those projects which have no references to "inet" using make clean and then make commands. But i cannot build those projects which include inet references.
Which commands I should use for building those projects which include inet projects references?

Answer (score 0):

Projects that reference an other project should be prepared by the author of the project to properly build from the command line, too. There is no such thing as a special command that make them work. Usually these projects assume that inet is installed alongside the actual project itself (i.e. in ../inet) and you should first somehow build the makefile before building the actual project. In SimuLTE for example you should first:

```
$ make makefiles
$ make
```

however this is project dependent of course.

Comment: Sir make makefiles and make is not working in my case.
DO i need to include my project in inet make file list?
Or is there any other way of building my project through terminal that includes inet references?

Comment: i have created a new workspace and included my project in it and it is working now.